# Getting a table with Mechanize in Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, html-table, nokogiri, mechanize

I'd like to get items from this table:

```
<table style="margin: auto;width: 800px" id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr class="TableHeader">
            <th >Game</th><th>Icon</th><th>Achievement</th>
                                <th>Achievers</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
                        <td><a href="Steam_Game_Info.php?AppID=440"><img alt="Logo" src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/07385eb55b5ba974aebbe74d3c99626bda7920b8.jpg" width=133 height=50 ></a></td>
                        <td>    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="AchievementBox" style="background-color: #347C17">
                <a href="Steam_Achievement_Info.php?AchievementID=169&amp;AppID=440">                <img  alt="Icon" src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/440/924764eea604817d3c14de9640ae6422c7cdfb7a.jpg" height='50' width='50'>
                </a>            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
            <td style="text-align: left" ><a href="Steam_Achievement_Info.php?AchievementID=169&amp;AppID=440">Race for the Pennant</a><br>Run 25 kilometers.</td>
            <td style="text-align: right">35505</td><td style="text-align: right">1.3</td>
```

The table has an id `myTable` so what I'd like to do is this:

```
go inside <tbody>
for each <tr> in table:
    do something; maybe go inside <td> or get a link from <href>
```

I have:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://astats.astats.nl/astats/TopListAchievements.php?DisplayType=2")

puts page.body
```

This prints the page but how do I actually iterate through the table rows?

Comment: Be very careful when it looks like you should use `<tbody>` or `<thead>` tags. Too often those are NOT in the HTML source, but are put there by a browser when you do a "view source". They won't be seen in the HTML if you directly download it, as would happen using Mechanize, so, as a result your selector would fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using css selector, to print text and href attribute values:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)
doc.css('table#myTable tbody td[3] a').each {|a|
  puts a.text, a[:href]
}
```

Comment: I think I edited as you were typing...how would I also get the description (ie Run 25 kilometres)? They're located just after the <a> tag

Comment: Do a Ctrl + F for "Run 25" and you'll see. Currently the program prints Achievement name/Link. I would like it to print Name/Link/Description.

Comment: @N1ghtshade3, I got it. Try `p a.next.next.text` (The first `next` is to get `<br>` tag, and the second `next` and `text` is to get the text)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I think I'm starting to get this.